# How to get a URL query string which has "?" inside?

Tags: php, httprequest

My URL looks like this:

```
www.xxx.com/?user&q=code/approve/realname&url=/?user&q=code/approve/myapp
```

When I use `$_REQUEST['url']` (PHP) to get the query string, it is just "/".
All of characters after ? (including) have gone.

BTW: I need to transfer such string including ? as the query string.

Comment: do you mean urlencode /?user&q=code/approve/myapp, and then urldecode after received?

Comment: You shouldn't need to urldecode: the webserver should handle that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URLEncode the value before sending it.

Look at the `urlencode()` function for PHP.

You value will look something like :

```
%3Fuser%26q%3Dcode%2Fapprove%2Fmyapp
```

Which will be correctly interpretated by the PHP query string parser.